# PowerShell - how to stop script processing elapsed events from Timer class

Tags: powershell, timer

I'm writing a PowerShell script in Visual Studio Code which is intended to run a function for every tick of a timer. Here is the code:

```
$timer = New-Object Timers.Timer
$timer.Interval = 1000
$timer.Enabled = $true

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -Action {Write-Host "Tick"}
```

The problem is that I don't seem to be able to stop the script using Ctrl+C which is what I would normally do, or indeed anything other than actually killing the terminal using the 'dustbin' icon. It just continues printing 'Tick'!

What's going on here? How would I stop this script gracefully?

Comment: `Get-EventSubscriber |Unregister-Event`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subscribe an action to an event using `Register-ObjectEvent`, it can be unregistered using the `Unregister-Event` cmdlet:

```
$timer = New-Object Timers.Timer
$timer.Interval = 1000
$timer.Enabled = $true

Register-ObjectEvent -SourceIdentifier MyElapsedTick -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -Action {Write-Host "Tick"}

<# ... #>

Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier MyElapsedTick
```

To enumerate existing subscribers (for when you forget to specify a `SourceIdenfitier` for example), use `Get-EventSubscriber`:

```
# This will unregister all event subscribers
Get-EventSubscriber |Unregister-Event
```

Comment: My question is not so much about how to unregister, more how to stop the script. So I need the script to know I'm trying to stop it, so that it can unregister... :)

Comment: @David I don't understand what you mean by "stop the script". The script/snippet you posted stops running as soon as `Register-ObjectEvent` returns, but the event subscription will persist until you unregister (or terminate the process)

Comment: Okay, thank you, I understand now. The event registration is independent of the script. So  Ctrl+D does stop the script (or would do, if the script hadn't already stopped after calling `Register-ObjectEvent`, as you say), but the events keep on ticking away.

Comment: What I didn't realise from your original post (my fault, not yours) is that I can call `Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier MyElapsedTick` outside of the script and it would still work. I assumed that the event registration would be scoped to the script, but that's clearly not the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
$timer = [System.Timers.Timer]::new()
$timer.Interval = 5000
$timer.AutoReset = $false
$timer.Enabled = $true
1..20 | % {
    if (!$timer.Enabled){
        exit
    }
    write-host $_, $timer.Enabled
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: I'am russian, i can read in English, but write in English it is hard for me.

Comment: @АлексейСеменов, You can always use Google translator or another translator. Your comment is well written.

Comment: @АлексейСеменов I very much appreciate your help, thank you!